# Angular 2 assigning form to variable not working #f="form" (submit)="onSubmit(f.value)"

Tags: angular, meteor, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I'm just going through the meteor angular 2 tutorial. In [step 4](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/adding-removing-objects-and-angular-event-handling) the angular 2 form binding with hash f equals form is used to bind the form to the variable f and secondly binding the onSubmit function. Neither is working for me. Has the Angular 2 API changed?

Not working HTML:

```
<form #f="form" (submit)="addParty(f.value)">
  <div>{{f.value}}</div>
</form>
```

Original HTML code for parties-form.html from the sample:

```
<form [ng-form-model]="partiesForm" #f="form" (submit)="addParty(f.value)">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" ng-control="name">
  <label>Description</label>
  <input type="text" ng-control="description">
  <label>Location</label>
  <input type="text" ng-control="location">
  <button>Add</button>
  <div>{{f}}</div>
  <div>{{f.value}}</div>
</form>
```

And the JS Component parties-form.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/angular2-meteor.d.ts" />

import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, Control, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {Parties} from 'collections/parties';

@Component({
    selector: 'parties-form'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'client/parties-form/parties-form.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class PartiesForm {
    partiesForm: ControlGroup;

    constructor() {
        var fb = new FormBuilder();
        this.partiesForm = fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            description: [''],
            location: ['', Validators.required]
        });
        // Test
        console.log(this.partiesForm.value);
    }

    addParty(party) {
        console.log("assParty", party);
        return true;
        if (this.partiesForm.valid) {
            Parties.insert({
                name: party.name,
                description: party.description,
                location: party.location
            });

            (<Control>this.partiesForm.controls['name']).updateValue('');
            (<Control>this.partiesForm.controls['description']).updateValue('');
            (<Control>this.partiesForm.controls['location']).updateValue('');
        }
    }

}
console.log("PartiesForm loaded");
```

I copied the meteor angular 2 sample, see exact code there. Other samples like [ng-book](http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/) use it too as onSubmit function

```
#f="form" (submit)="onSubmit(f.value)"
```

Comment: Problem was a caching issue. Going through the tutorial the first version was caches. Not sure, but I think meteor should do a cache busting automatically however I needed to manually delete the cache to get it functioning.

Comment: You could answer your own question and accept it (after some cool-down time) then it wouldn't stay open as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was a caching issue. Going through the tutorial the first version was caches. Not sure, but I think meteor should do a cache busting automatically however I needed to manually delete the cache to get it functioning.